# Can I specify different Graph Api version in the Facebook Login Url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API version 3.1 for my Facebook application. I want to change it to Graph API version 3.3. But before upgrading the API version, I want to test whether it will work correctly or not. I don't want to upgrade the API version in the Facebook developers website.
Can I specify v3.3 in the URL directly without changing the default Graph API version in the app settings?

Comment: You can upgrade the API version for people with a role in the app only, directly from the app dashboard.

Comment: _“Can I specify v3.3 in the URL directly”_ - you could, but you would have to do this for _all_ API calls your app makes - doing it for the login dialog URL only would not be a correct way to test this; because then you would be testing the login part against v3.3 only, but all API calls you app makes in the background would still be made against the older version.

Comment: Actually I am using Facebook Login only for Signup/Login purpose only. My fear is that, if I change the API version in app dashboard to higher version, will I be able to downgrade it again or not?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to downgrade it again.